# how to add an image on jasper inside spring mvc web application

Tags: image, spring, url, jasper-reports

i want to add several image to my PDF report, here is my views.xml

```
<bean id="form_b" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
    p:url="/WEB-INF/jasper/form_b.jasper">
    <property name="headers">
        <props>
            <prop key="Content-Disposition">
                attachment; filename=form_b.pdf
            </prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

i have an image file located here: "WEB-INF/images/logo.jpg"
how can i embed it to my jasper pdf report ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is, is to insert it in you jrxml file:

```
<image scaleImage="RetainShape" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Bottom">
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="758" height="60" />
    <imageExpression>"reports/test.png"</imageExpression>
</image>
```

In this case the images are located in WEB-INF/classes/reports.

I would not like to place the images in an other directory then WEB-INF/classes (or a subdirectory of that), because placeing them there (WEB-INF/classes) makes it easy to write unit tests that check if the jasper reports works fine.